# Error: Non-numeric character in statement at label (1)

Tags: fortran

This is the program I compile on ubuntu 14.04 using

```
f95 First.f -o First
```

and the program is

```
!My first program
program first
print *,'This is my first program'
end program first
```

And I get the following error

```
Error:Non-numeric character at statement label at (1)
First.f:2.1:

program first
```

How do you address this error?

Answer (score 44):

Rename your file from `First.f` to `First.f90`.

You have encountered an issue which is easily avoided.  Compilers generally assume that `.f` files are written in what is known as *fixed source form*, which has been obsolescent since Fortran 90.  With the `.f90` suffix your compiler should expect to encounter *free source form* and not complain as it has done. In fixed source form, cols 1-6 in each line are reserved for a (numeric) statement label.

Now, use your favorite Fortran resources to understand, if you care, the differences between the two source forms.

Comment: I'm trying to teach myself Fortran using gfortran-9 and the recent 2018 standard. Is there an extension specific to each Fortran standard?

Answer (score 4):

As the other answer mentions, free source form is a great idea, but

If for some reason you have to keep the program in fixed source form, then leave 6 spaces (first 6 columns) and start from the 7th column.

> The format had the first five columns reserved for statement labels. The first column was used to denote comments by a letter C. The sixth column was used to denote a statement continuation (by inserting any character other than a zero '0'). The last 8 columns were used for card identification and sequencing, which was pretty valuable if you dropped your deck of cards on the floor! The character coding for punched cards had only a limited set of characters and was upper case only.

For this reason, the compiler expects numerical statement labels or blank space for the first 6 columns. `Error:Non-numeric character at statement label at (1)` is the result of this.

[Source](https://riptutorial.com/fortran/example/11457/fixed-source-form)

---

TLDR: if you must use fixed source form (`.f` extension) leave 6 blank spaces and start from the 7th column like this :

```
      program first
      print *,'This is my first program'
      end program first
```