# Compile error for a simple Fortran 77 program

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran77

I copied and pasted in Sublime Text the following program from a Fortran 77 [tutorial](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fortran_77_Tutorial#Fortran_77_Basics):

```
program circle
      real r, area

c This program reads a real number r and prints
c the area of a circle with radius r.

      write (*,*) 'Give radius r:'
      read  (*,*) r
      area = 3.14159*r*r
      write (*,*) 'Area = ', area

      stop
      end
```

I saved it as `circle.f` and compiled from the Terminal (macOS Sierra):

```
gfortran circle.f
```

It returned the error message:

```
circle.f:1:1:

 program circle
 1
Error: Non-numeric character in statement label at (1)
circle.f:1:1:

 program circle
 1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
```

How can I fix it? ([The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26887826/758077) for another similar question does not solve the problem.)

Comment: Try add 6 spaces before `program circle`.

Comment: @apocalypse: that solved the problem, thanks a lot! (Shall I delete my question?) It is said in the tutorial that "Blank spaces are ignored in Fortran 77. So if you remove all blanks in a Fortran 77 program, the program is still acceptable to a compiler but almost unreadable to humans." It is unclear to me why adding the spaces would make it works.

Comment: A quick search with "fortran must have space" (I didn't know what to search when I posted this question) on Google returns that "The Fortran 77 syntax requires that you give 6 spaces before any commands. These 6 spaces originate from the punched card version of Fortran. After the first 6 spaces, you may place additional spaces for indentation if you wish."

Comment: just to be particular, this is not "fortran 77" syntax, it is fixed-form fortran, which is still supported by the current fortran standards.  Its good to learn since you will undoubtedly encounter old code, but for new work you can use free-form if you like.

Comment: @agentp: thanks for the helpful information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortran 77 has fixed form source. Only characters between the 7th and the 73rd column can be used for statements. (The first 6 characters are used to declare the whole line a comment, as numeric labels, or to denote this line to be a continuation of the previous.) The 74th and later characters are simply ignored.

Inside this range, spaces are ignored. So the following lines would be identical:

```
column   1    1    2    2    3    3    4    4
1   5    0    5    0    5    0    5    0    5
-----------------------------------------------
      if (i .le. 10) call my_sub(i)
      if(i.le.10)callmy_sub(i)
          i   f ( i. le .10) cal lmy_ sub(i)
```

I leave it up to you to decide which one is easiest to read.

But if you start at the first character, even with the starting "program" statement, the compiler will complain. It expected a `c`, `C`, `!` (to declare the whole line a comment) or a digit as the beginning of a numeric label.

Comment: Quick note: I'm not sure whether `c`, `C`, and `!` are the only possible markers for a comment. But apparently `p` is not ;)

Comment: in standard f77 'C' or asterisk can be used in col 1 for comment. Newer versions allow the `!` in fixed form as well since it can initiate a comment anywhere (Except where it would be a continuation marker )