# How to compile .f file without unclassifiable statment and unexpected end of files errors

Tags: r, fortran, gfortran, subroutine

I'm new to Fortran, and I need it to speed my code in R, am using gfortran in Arch Linux: here is one of my codes :

```
subroutine pkfull(m,n,o,a,b,ps,pk)
    implicit none
    integer,intent(in) :: m,n,o
    integer :: i,j,k
    double precision,intent(in) :: a(o)
    double precision,intent(in) :: b(o)
    double precision,intent(in) :: ps(m,n,o)
    double precision,intent(inout) :: pk(m,n,o)
    do 20,i=1,m
      do 15, j =1,n
       do 10, k=1,o
          pk(i,j,k) = ps(i,j,k)*b(k)+a(k)
10         end do 
15    end do    
20     end do  
end subroutine pkfull
```

The Error i get  after i run: $R CMD SHLIB pkfull.f

```
   gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fpic  -g -O2  -c pkfull.f -o pkfull.o
   pkfull.f:12:24:

   12 |                   pk(i,j,k) = ps(i,j,k)
      |                        1
   Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
   pkfull.f:16:2:

   16 | end subroutine pkfull
   |  1
    Error: Non-numeric character in statement label at (1)
   f951: Error: Unexpected end of file in ‘pkfull.f’
   make: *** [/usr/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf:190: pkfull.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Sorry it is  : pk(i,j,k) = ps(i,j,k)*b(k)+a(k) in the error as well as in the code

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the correction. Please also take the [tour] to find out how to use the site. Also, the error points to a label number 12 .There is no such label in your code. Your error messages should exactly correspond to your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Non-numeric character in statement at label (1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26887689/error-non-numeric-character-in-statement-at-label-1) In particular, the more informative error (you receive many trying to compile this as-is) is "Error: Non-numeric character in statement label". The top answer to the linked question explains you need `f90`, not `f`. Renaming the file to `pkfull.f90` allows it to compile just fine on my system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your code and tried to compile. It might simply be a problem with spaces at the start of each line. Make sure that all lines start in column 7, reserve the first column for comments, the 6th for any continuation marker and put any line numbers in column 2 onwards. So your code should be as follows:

```
      SUBROUTINE pkfull(m,n,o,a,b,ps,pk)
      IMPLICIT NONE
      INTEGER,INTENT(IN) :: m,n,o
      integer :: i,j,k
      double precision,intent(in) :: a(o)
      double precision,intent(in) :: b(o)
      double precision,intent(in) :: ps(m,n,o)
      double precision,intent(inout) :: pk(m,n,o)
      do 20,i=1,m
       do 15, j =1,n
        do 10, k=1,o
           pk(i,j,k) = ps(i,j,k)*b(k)+a(k)
 10     end do
 15    end do
 20   end do
      end subroutine pkfull
```

Comment: Welcome, this is probably correct. However, we have many similar questions and answer and therefore we should mainly close new answers asking the same as duplicates instead of answering all of them again.